# i have a dynnamic html table so how can i add multiple rows with same name and id+1 in django database its only added first row in database

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-models

i have javascript to increment id as a +1 so how can i add those html rows into database  i am trying to add those dynamiclly rows which is genrated by javascript but i am not able to add those rows please help me

models.py

```
class New_Order(models.Model):
sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
hscode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Product_Category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Finish = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Edge = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Product_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Product_Nomenclature = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Product_Type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Length = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Breadth = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Thickness = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Patio_Pack = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Crate = models.IntegerField()
Measure = models.IntegerField()
Measure_Unit = models.IntegerField()
Pcs_or_Crate = models.IntegerField()
Crate_Start = models.IntegerField()
Crate_End = models.IntegerField()
Crate_Buffer = models.IntegerField()
Container_Qty = models.IntegerField()
Percentage = models.IntegerField()
Desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Price = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.hscode
```

i am trying through name but all name are same in dynamiclly table so those values not adding in database can you all please guide me how its possible

views.py

```
     def pro(request):
prod = Product_Catagory.objects.all()
any =  Finishe.objects.all()
edg = Edge.objects.all()
prodn = Product_Name.objects.all()
prodnn = Product_Nomenclature.objects.all()
prodt = Product_Type.objects.all()
len = Length.objects.all()
bre = Breadth.objects.all()
thick = Thicknes.objects.all()
pat = Patio_Pack.objects.all()
context = {'prod':prod, 'any':any, 'edg':edg, 'prodn':prodn, 'prodnn':prodnn, 'prodt':prodt, 'len':len, 'bre':bre, 'thick':thick, 'pat':pat}
if request.method == "POST":
    hscode = request.POST['hscode']
    PC = request.POST['PC']
    Finish = request.POST['Finish']
    Edges = request.POST['Edges']
    PN = request.POST['PN']
    PNN = request.POST['PNN']
    PT = request.POST['PT']
    Lengths = request.POST['Lengths']
    Breath = request.POST['Breath']
    Thickness = request.POST['Thickness']
    Patio = request.POST['Patio']
    Crate = request.POST['Crate']
    Measure = request.POST['Measure']
    UMC = request.POST['UMC']
    PCS = request.POST['PCS']
    start = request.POST['start']
    end = request.POST['end']
    buffer = request.POST['buffer']
    conq = request.POST['conq']
    per = request.POST['per']
    desc = request.POST['desc']
    price = request.POST['price']
    ins = New_Order( hscode=hscode, Product_Category=PC, Finish=Finish, Edge=Edges, Product_Name=PN, Product_Nomenclature=PNN, Product_Type=PT, Length=Lengths, Breadth=Breath, Thickness=Thickness, Patio_Pack=Patio, Crate=Crate, Measure=Measure, Measure_Unit=UMC, Pcs_or_Crate=PCS, Crate_Start=start, Crate_End=end, Crate_Buffer=buffer, Container_Qty=conq, 
Percentage=per, Desc=desc, Price=price)
ins.save()

return render(request, 'profoma.html', context)
```

Html:

```
       <table  id="FinancialDataTable" class="table table-bordered border-dark"
        style="display: block; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">HS_Code</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Product Category</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Finish</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Edges</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Product Name</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Product Nomenclature</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI Product Type</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Length Dimension</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Breath Dimension</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Thickness Dimension</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Patio Pack</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI No. of Crate</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI Unit of Measure</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI unit of Measure/Crate</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI No. of Pcs/Crate</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI Crate No. Start</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI Crate No. End</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Crate Buffer No.</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Max Container Qty.</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Percentage</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">Description</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI Billable Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI Price</th>
                <th scope="col" style="border: solid;">PI Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <form action="/pro" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
            <tr>

                <td><select name="hscode" id="hscode">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>HS_Code</option>
                        {% for prod in prod %}
                        <option>{{prod.HS_CODE}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="PC" id="PC">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Product Category</option>
                        {% for prod in prod %}
                        <option>{{prod.Product_Catagory_Name}}</option>
                        {% endfor%}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="Finish" id="Finish">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Finish</option>
                        {% for any in any %}
                        <option>{{any.finish}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="Edges" id="Edges">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Edge</option>
                        {% for edg in edg %}
                        <option>{{edg.edge}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="PN" id="PN">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Product Name</option>
                        {% for prodn in prodn %}
                        <option>{{prodn.Product_Name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="PNN" id="PNN">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Product Nomenclature</option>
                        {% for prodnn in prodnn %}
                        <option>{{prodnn.Product_Nomenclature_Name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="PT" id="PT">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Product Type</option>
                        {% for prodt in prodt %}
                        <option>{{prodt.Product_Type}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="Lengths" id="Lengths">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Length</option>
                        {% for len in len %}
                        <option>{{len.length_dimension}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="Breath" id="Breath">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Breath</option>
                        {% for bre in bre %}
                        <option>{{bre.breadth_dimension}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="Thickness" id="Thickness">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Thickness</option>
                        {% for thick in thick %}
                        <option>{{thick.thickness_dimension }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><select name="Patio" id="Patio">
                        <option disabled="true" selected>Patio Pack</option>
                        {% for pat in pat %}
                        <option>{{pat.patio_pack_configuration}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select></td>
                <td><input name="Crate" id="Crate"></td>
                <td><input name="Measure" id="Measure"></td>
                <td><input name="UMC" id="UMC"></td>
                <td><input name="PCS" id="PCS"></td>
                <td><input name="start" id="start"></td>
                <td><input name="end" id="end"></td>
                <td><input name="buffer" id="buffer"></td>
                <td><input name="conq" id="conq"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="per" id="per"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price"></td>
            </tr>
            <input type="submit" value="Next">
        </form>
        </tbody>
```

Add New Row

js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*-------------------NEW TABLE ROW -------------------------*/

   $('.btn').click(function () {

$('#FinancialDataTable tbody').append($('#FinancialDataTable tbody tr:last').clone());

$('#FinancialDataTable tr').each(function (i) {
    if (i === 1)
        return;
    var selectinput = $(this).find('select');
    var textinput = $(this).find('input');
    var textarea = $(this).find('textarea');
    selectinput.eq(0).attr('id', 'hscode' + i);
    selectinput.eq(1).attr('id', 'PC' + i);
    selectinput.eq(2).attr('id', 'Finish' + i);
    selectinput.eq(3).attr('id', 'Edge' + i);
    selectinput.eq(4).attr('id', 'PN' + i);
    selectinput.eq(5).attr('id', 'PNN' + i);
    selectinput.eq(6).attr('id', 'PT' + i);
    selectinput.eq(7).attr('id', 'Length' + i);
    selectinput.eq(8).attr('id', 'Breadth' + i);
    selectinput.eq(9).attr('id', 'Thickness' + i);
    selectinput.eq(10).attr('id', 'Patio' + i);
    textinput.eq(0).attr('id', 'Crate' + i);
    textinput.eq(1).attr('id', 'Measure' + i);
    textinput.eq(2).attr('id', 'UMC' + i);
    textinput.eq(3).attr('id', 'PCS' + i);
    textinput.eq(4).attr('id', 'start' + i);
    textinput.eq(5).attr('id', 'end' + i);
    textinput.eq(6).attr('id', 'buffer' + i);
    textinput.eq(7).attr('id', 'conq' + i);
    textinput.eq(8).attr('id', 'per' + i);
    textinput.eq(9).attr('id', 'desc' + i);
    textinput.eq(10).attr('id', 'qty' + i);
    textinput.eq(11).attr('id', 'price' + i);
});
```

});

Comment: Could you be more clear what the error is? Also, that's a lot of overwhelming code; can you shorten it to just the part that triggers the bug?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Basically i have a html table and a js to increment in id so now if i save the table in database so only one entry is added